# List passed into method and deserialised becomes empty once method returns

Tags: java, generics, serialization, collections

I have a method:

```
static <E extends NotesAttached> void deserialise(List<E> list, String type) {
    String fileName = "C:/temp/SalesModel." + type + ".list.ser";
    try {
        FileInputStream serFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(serFile);
        list = (List<E>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        serFile.close();
        System.out.println(type + "s deserialised successfully, " + list.size() + " retrieved");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
    List<Deal> deals = new ArrayList<Deal>();
    deserialise(deals, "Deal");
    System.out.println("Number of deals deserialised: " + deals.size());
```

The list is populated when its in the method, but when it returns, its empty. I don't understand why, would appreciate it if someone could explain.

The output is as follows:

Deals deserialised successfully, 2522 retrieved
Number of deals deserialised: 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list you've deserialized doesn't "become empty" - but the `deals` variable doesn't refer to the list you've just deserialized... it refers to the same empty list that it did before you called the method. Changing the value of the `list` parameter within the method does *nothing* to the argument you've passed, because Java uses pass by value.

Rather than having a `void` method, you'd be better off returning the list:

```
static <E extends NotesAttached> List<E> deserialise(String type)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String fileName = "C:/temp/SalesModel." + type + ".list.ser";
    FileInputStream serFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(serFile);
    try {
        List<E> list = (List<E>) in.readObject();
        System.out.println(type + "s deserialised successfully, " + list.size() + " retrieved");
        return list;
    } finally {
        // See notes
        in.close();
        serFile.close();
    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
List<Deal> deals = deserialise(deals, "Deal");
System.out.println("Number of deals deserialised: " + deals.size());
```

You'll need to deal with the `ClassNotFoundException` and the `IOException`, but they're better off being dealt with outside the method anyway - you almost certainly *don't* want to just catch them, dump a stack trace and continue as if nothing had gone wrong.

That's not *quite* right, as you really want to close the streams regardless of other errors. If you can use Java 7, you can use a try-with-resources statement instead:

```
static <E extends NotesAttached> List<E> deserialise(String type)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String fileName = "C:/temp/SalesModel." + type + ".list.ser";
    try (FileInputStream serFile = new FileInputStream(fileName),
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(serFile)) {
        List<E> list = (List<E>) in.readObject();
        System.out.println(type + "s deserialised successfully, " + list.size() + " retrieved");
        return list;
    }
}
```

If you're stuck with Java 6, I'd probably use nested try/finally blocks - or *only* close the `FileInputStream`, given that the `ObjectInputStream` doesn't hold onto any unmanaged resources anyway.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I was just confused because if I do something like list.add("random text") in my method that is still in the list in my calling method? Like someone else andswered, I think I am just reassigning my reference variable in the original example, rather than using it.

Comment: @Jules: It sounds like you should put down serialization etc and go back to the basics of how Java references and objects work. It's *really* fundamental to working properly with Java.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign `in.readObject()` to `list`, you are not changing the list that you instantiate outside of the method - you are only changing the `list` reference to point to the result of `in.readObject()` instead of the list you pass in.

You need to return `in.readObject()` from your method and then assign the result to a new variable:

```
List<Deal> deals = deserialise(deals, "Deal");
```

Alternatively you could modify the passed-in list in `deserialise` (but this is not recommended, since modifying passed-in collections is not a good way to return data from methods):

```
list.addAll((List<E>) in.readObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is pass-by-value, so you have to return the deserialized list, ,not assign it to the input parameter